# After forcing shutdown during early startup, POST takes super long, and other problems

Tags: hard-drive

I recently tried Wake On Lan with my new phone and after it worked, used the power button to shut it down. This was after the POST beep. That was not a good idea... now, POST takes very long to finish, and when booting, Ubuntu says "gave up waiting for boot device" and something like "ALERT! /something/ubuntu--vg-mapper does not exist. Dropping to shell!" (I forgot the exact file name), although typing "exit" in the shell will continue booting normally. My data (secondary) hard drive is also gone from the list! I think it's broken, but it does spin up after power on.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is Ubuntu on your phone or a computer? Either way, try removing the battery and unplugging the charger before holding the power button down for a while.

Comment: @Zacharee1 POST now takes normal time, but Ubuntu now still gives me an error when booting ("gave up waiting for root device" and "/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root does not exist. dropping to shell!", typing exit will continue normal boot). And I have Ubuntu on a desktop.

Comment: @Zacharee1 The missing hard drive is now also accessible again.

Comment: Did you say you tried boot-repair?

Comment: I'm sorry, what is boot-repair? Another thing, after I posted my last comment, I went to work, and I just came home and everything worked normally again. I don't know what the hell I did after doing what you said, but it works now, thanks?! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Zacharee1 for helping me with this one.

Four simple steps to solve this (make sure the power is OFF before doing this!):

1. Pull out the power cord. On a phone, remove the battery.
2. Press the power button. The power led will likely turn on and briefly after that turn back off.
3. Put the cord or battery back in.
4. Turn the power back on, and everything should work again.

What you just did is reset your PC/phone. It means that all volatile memories (such as the RAM or BIOS cache) that may possibly have retained some bad data will be reset, although any non-volatile memories such as your hard drive will be unaffected, so don't worry.

You may have to boot into the system once more for it to fully fix the problem. After that, the next boot will succeed normally.

Also, don't forget to go back into the BIOS setup after doing this, as many settings will reset to factory defaults when you power cycle a device. Usually, the time will remain in order, unless you took so long that the battery that powers the clock will have died. But that takes several months.